# Create a PostgreSQL constraint to prevent unique combination rows

Tags: postgresql, exclusion-constraint

Imagine you have a simple table:

```
name | is_active
----------------
A    | 0
A    | 0
B    | 0
C    | 1
...  | ...
```

I need to create a special unique constraint which fails on following situation:
different `is_active` values can't co-exist for the same `name` value.

Example of permitted condition:

*Note: simple multi-column unique index won't permit combination like this.*

```
A    | 0
A    | 0
B    | 0
```

Example of permitted condition:

```
A    | 0
B    | 1
```

Example of failed condition:

```
A    | 0
A    | 1
-- should be prevented, because `A 0` exists
-- same name, but different `is_active`
```

Ideally, I need unique constraint or unique partial index. Triggers are more problematic for me.

Double `A,0` allowed, but `(A,0) (A,1)` isn't.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use an exclusion constraint with [`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html),

```
-- This is needed
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

Then we add a constraint that says:

*"We can't have 2 rows that have the same `name` and different `is_active`"*:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD CONSTRAINT only_one_is_active_value_per_name
    EXCLUDE  USING gist
    ( name WITH =, 
      is_active WITH <>      -- if boolean, use instead:
                             -- (is_active::int) WITH <>
    );
```

Some notes:

- `is_active` can be integer or boolean, makes no difference for the exclusion constraint. (actually it does, if the column is boolean you need to use `(is_active::int) WITH <>`.)
- Rows where `name` or `is_active` is null will be ignored by the constraint and thus allowed.
- The constraint makes sense only if the table has more columns. Otherwise, if the table has only these 2 columns, a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(name)` alone would be easier and more appropriate. I don't see any reason for storing multiple identical rows.
- The design violates 2NF. While the exclusion constraint will save us from update anomalies, it may not from performance issues. If you have for example 1000 rows with `name = 'A'` and you want to to update is_active status from 0 to 3, all 1000 will have to be updated. You should examine whether normalizing the design would be more efficient. (Normalizing meaning in this case to remove is_active status from the table and add a 2-column table with name, is_active and a unique constraint on `(name)`. If `is_active` is boolean, it could be totally stripped and the extra table just a single column table, storing only the "active" names.)

Comment: is_active can't be boolean, `ERROR:  data type boolean has no default operator class for access method "gist"`

Comment: @EvanCarroll I can't remember how well I tested this when I posted. But it works with `int` and `smallint`.

Comment: Also works using `EXCLUDE  USING gist (name WITH =, (is_active::int) WITH <>)` if it's boolean. And the question has `0` and `1`, not `true` and `false` so it's rather unlikely I tested with booleans ;)

Comment: All good, I used an exclusion constraint over https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/175922/2639 and I had a problem using a booleans so I went searching. I thought btree_gist covered bools but it doesn't.

Comment: The Postgres docs have [a nice example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html#id-1.11.7.16.7) of this in action, where a zoo cage can only contain one type of animal. Worth adding to the solution maybe.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a case where you can use a unique index. You can test the condition in a trigger, e.g.:

```
create or replace function a_table_trigger()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
declare
    active int;
begin
    select is_active into active
    from a_table
    where name = new.name;

    if found and active is distinct from new.is_active then
        raise exception 'The value of is_active for "%" should be %', new.name, active;
    end if;
    return new;
end $$;
```

[Test it here.](http://rextester.com/VWQ97617)