# MySQL constraint to prevent combinations of columns

Tags: mysql, constraint, mysql-8.0

I have a table that represents files in directories.

```
dir   | file
----------------
dir_A | file_0
dir_A | file_1
dir_A | file_1
dir_B | file_2
dir_C | file_3
...   | ...
```

I want to put a constraint on that table to make sure a file can never be in 2 directories. But the same file can be in the same directory multiple times.

Example of permitted condition:

```
dir_A | file_1
dir_A | file_1
dir_B | file_2
```

Example of failed condition:

```
dir_A | file_1
dir_B | file_1
-- should be prevented, because `dir_A file_1` exists
-- same file, but different directory
```

The question [has been asked for PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161506/create-a-postgresql-constraint-to-prevent-unique-combination-rows) with solution:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;
ALTER TABLE table_name
    ADD CONSTRAINT only_one_dir_per_file
        EXCLUDE USING gist ( file WITH =, dir WITH <> );
```

I was wondering if the same could be done with MySQL?

Comment: Yes, this can be solved if you add a second table and an FK from this to the second table.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Triggers for that.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE files_dir (
>   `dir` VARCHAR(5),
>   `file` VARCHAR(6)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO files_dir
>   (`dir`, `file`)
> VALUES
>   ('dir_A', 'file_0'),
>   ('dir_A', 'file_1'),
>   ('dir_A', 'file_1'),
>   ('dir_B', 'file_2'),
>   ('dir_C', 'file_3');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER before_file_insert 
>     BEFORE INSERT ON files_dir
>     FOR EACH ROW 
>  BEGIN
>  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM files_dir WHERE `file`= NEW.`file` AND `dir` = NEW.`dir`) then
>   BEGIN
>   END;
>  ELSE
>     IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM files_dir WHERE `file`= NEW.`file`) THEN
>           SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
>       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "file has another directory";
>     END IF;
>    END IF;
>  END;
> ```

> ```
>  INSERT INTO files_dir
>   (`dir`, `file`)
> VALUES
> ('dir_A', 'file_1');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>  INSERT INTO files_dir
>   (`dir`, `file`)
> VALUES
> ('dir_B', 'file_1');
> ```
>
> ```
> file has another directory
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM files_dir;
> ```
>
> ```
> dir   | file  
> :---- | :-----
> dir_A | file_0
> dir_A | file_1
> dir_A | file_1
> dir_B | file_2
> dir_C | file_3
> dir_A | file_1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a38f64cc1e88cf1f60fc6f28d56ce72c)*

For an BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER you can do something eual.

Of course you can always change your insert statement with a join like ypercubeᵀᴹ already said.

Comment: In my case it is possible for the same file to be in the same directory multiple times. I should have been more specific in my question. My bad. I've made an edit now.

Comment: @MaartenDhondt i change my answer, for your new requirements